# Number to time hour and hour

Tags: vba, excel, time, numbers

I'm trying to find the total productivity of each employee in a week. The production time is tracked in an excel. However, the tracking time is in number format. I need to convert the number to a time format. Each working day has 8 hours production.

Currently, I've designed a macro for getting the time in hours and minutes format, however, after a certain point, the value is inaccurate. Please find the below code.

```
Sub test

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim TemUtl As Worksheet

    Set wks = Sheets("Working")
    Set TemUtl = Sheets("Team Utilisation")

    Dim TMMBRTimR As Range
    Dim TMMBRTimC As Range
    Set TMMBRTimR = TemUtl.Range("A3:A32")

    Dim TiMLstrw As Long
    TiMLstrw = TemUtl.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each TMMBRTimC In TMMBRTimR.Rows

        TMMBRTimC.Offset(0, 11).Value = 
        Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wks.Range("G:G"), 
        wks.Range("C:C"), _
        Trim("8"), wks.Range("B:B"), TMMBRTimC, wks.Range("H:H"), "<>Process 
        Training") / 1440, "HH:MM")

    Next TMMBRTimC

End sub
```

I have two tabs in the excel files, one is `Working` and other is `Team Utilisation`.

The sum total for the productivity is taken from the `Working` tab, hope the `sumifs` formula is understandable.

Comment: What are the units of the values being summed?

Comment: yes the values are summed , and sometimes the sum amount will be like 2345 or 4000 or so on. The number in numeric value. I need the hour and Minute of those figures. eg . (2345/1440)....

Comment: What are the *units* of the values being summed?  Hours? Days?

Comment: The Units are just numbers , which means the each and every row will be captured by difference Employee . working tab range consist of  ( User ID ,Emp Name ,Aux Code ,Aux Description ,Total Time(Mins) ,Comments ,Date)

Time in minutes column contains the minutes in number format (without) decimal.

Comment: So the units are minutes?

Comment: yes , the units are minutes . it need to get converted in Hours and Minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Format({calc here}, "[h]:mm")
```

that will allow for times >24hrs

EDIT: seems like that doesn't work in VBA as it does on a worksheet, so try

```
Application.Text({calc here}, "[h]:mm")
```

Comment: I agree with you , i'm using the same format for the cells as well as in the macro as well . I'm getting the exact value if the numerator is less than 1440 , but if the numerator is above 1440 then the value is showing a lesser hours and minutes